# Why the "Safe delete..." function is not accessible in IntelliJ on properties?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, refactoring

When I open the Structure window in IntelliJ IDEA, the *Save delete...* option is not accessible for any of the **properties**:

[image]

However, the very same function works from the **fields**:

[image]

When used from the field, it *anyway* deletes the whole "property", i.e. the field and its getter and setter methods.

Why cannot I access the very same function on the whole property? And the function *is* in the menu and it is greyed out, so under what condition it *is* accessible?

I created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170415, so I am wandering what the answer from JetBrains is.

Answer (score 2):

Actions such as refactorings are available in the "context" of where in the code structure the carat is positioned.

Therefore if you click on the code for a field, you will see certain refactorings. Or if you position the carat on the class name, you will see other refactorings.

As for how this related to the project structure (alt - 7) - you will notice that if you click on an item in the project structure and then hit f4 (Jump to Source), it will navigate to the exact position in the source code window that relates to that item.

I have often used f4 to navigate from the project structure to the code, and you will notice the available refactorings are identical (between structure view and the code pane).

Now, interestingly (I never tried this before now), if you enable "Properties" (with the P) in the project structure and position the cursor on a property, hit f4 - it does *not* navigate to the code.

I suspect that there is no link between the "property" and "PSI" structure of the java code (which in turn maps to a specific line in the code pane). Perhaps this is an oversight in intellij, or perhaps it is meant that way since the property can indeed represent 3 different pieces of code (the field, the getter and the setter).

To me it would appear most logical to associate the property with the field itself, so that Jump to Source would navigate to the field (and therefore refactorings would be available) but this isn't the case.

Comment: Well, so the fact that the item "Safe delete..." is on the menu for the property, but greyed out, is a bug in IntelliJ?

Comment: Perhaps more of an oversite. The "Propery" seems more a form of "meta information" rather than a direct link to a specific point in the code. Therefore the link (and context sensitive refactorings) is not available.

Comment: This sounds plausible, however still I think that they (= JetBrains) should *either* remove the menu items completely *or* make them available. So it is a *bug* in the design of the IDE. And it actually consumed some of my time before I realized that I have to uncollapse the property and the action can be performed directly on the field.